# Using script as an ES6 module results in no-undef warnings

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I made a script to generate some made up accounts and transactions and running the script on it's own is fine. It generates the 2 lists as I expect, however I need to use the lists in another file. When I export the variables at the end and re-import them in another file I get a pile of no-undef warnings and my build fails.

I'm assuming this is because my export objects are containing the functions. How can I force the functions to just generate the values so I can export them properly?

```
randomint = (start, end) => {
  let diff = end - start;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * diff) + start
}

chance = (rate=0.5) => {
  return Math.random() > rate ? true : false;
}

pad = (n, width, z) => {
  z = z || '0';
  n = n + '';
  return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
}

NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS = 10
NUM_OF_TXS = randomint(30, 40)

let accounts = [];
let transactions = [];


for (let i=0; i< NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS; i++) {
  accounts.push({
    id: i,
    ref: `SMAR_A${pad(i, 3)}`,
    account: randomint(10000000, 99999999),
    sortcode: randomint(100000, 9999999),
    fraud: chance(0.1),
    balance: Math.round(Math.random() * 85000, 2)
  })
}

for (let t = 0; t < NUM_OF_TXS; t++) {
  // Lookup a random account number to generate a transaction for
  acct_num = randomint(0, accounts.length - 1 )

  transactions.push({
    ref: accounts[acct_num].ref,
    deposit: Math.round(Math.random() * 85000, 2),
    account: accounts[acct_num].account,
    sortcode: accounts[acct_num].sortcode,
  })
};

export accounts;
export transactions;
```

I have tried a range of exports and imports and I'm having no luck.

```
  Line 1:    'randomint' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 6:    'chance' is not defined           no-undef
  Line 10:   'pad' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 16:   'NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 17:   'NUM_OF_TXS' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 17:  'randomint' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 23:  'NUM_OF_ACCOUNTS' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 26:  'pad' is not defined              no-undef
  Line 27:  'randomint' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 28:  'randomint' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 29:  'chance' is not defined           no-undef
  Line 34:  'NUM_OF_TXS' is not defined       no-undef
  Line 35:   'acct_num' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 35:  'randomint' is not defined        no-undef
  Line 38:  'acct_num' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 40:  'acct_num' is not defined         no-undef
  Line 41:  'acct_num' is not defined         no-undef
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I improve how my exports work? I would like to understand my errors & mistakes so I can learn more and improve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour comes from javascript strict-mode. Your code works in "sloppy mode". In particular, you are encountering this rule (taken from the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) of strict mode):

> Strict mode makes it impossible to accidentally create global
>   variables. In normal JavaScript mistyping a variable in an assignment
>   creates a new property on the global object and continues to "work"
>   (although future failure is possible: likely, in modern JavaScript).
>   Assignments, which would accidentally create global variables, instead
>   throw an error in strict mode:

In your code, this occurs here:

```
randomint = (start, end) => {
  let diff = end - start;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * diff) + start
}
```

And all the other places that introduces a variable without using `const`, `let`, or `var`.

It's a simple fix, just add `const` or `let` in front of every variable:

```
const randomint = (start, end) => {
  let diff = end - start;
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * diff) + start
}

const chance = (rate=0.5) => {
  return Math.random() > rate ? true : false;
}
// etc
```

You're only encountering this with modules since modules have strict mode enabled by default, and normal scripts don't.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explainer! I have been very sloppy in my code! I really should have read the errors properly before posting. Guess it will help others who also are having the same issue!

Answer (score 1):

Then just declare them. Instead of

```
randomint = (start, end) => {
```

write

```
const randomint = (start, end) => {
```

Etc.

Comment: That has fixed it. I can't believe I am such an idiot! For some reason that didn't even occur to me as the issue. 

Thank you and in future I will read the errors and actually think about what it means!